# React: How to re-render UI changes for multi client web app

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, socket.io, server-side-rendering

i'm searching a while for a solution how to re-render UI changes on a react web page when multiple client have this page already open or will open this page.

A short example:

I've got changed the position of a square box via drag and drop on the page. As a client i see the box on the new position. Someone who has this page open in the browser will receive an update and see the new position as well.
[image]

I'm new to react and first i tried to build a multi page app with a nav bar and css design..so far so good.
The next step was to change a background of a  element via button press. Then i thought when the color is changed for everyone who is connecting on IP:Port in the local network. But the second client didnt see any changes. I saw some examples of chat rooms and they are using socket.io to display incoming messages. Is this what i need to make the changes visible for other clients and using ssr?

Thanks for any help how to start this project.